# Why doesn't this program stop?

Tags: c

My instructor has asked us to follow the variables through this code and determine when the variables change. He says the inputs should be

```
8, 4, 2, 1
```

I have compiled and run the code to he me understand it but it doesn't stop. It just ouputs "Feed me two numbers please:" over and over. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c=0;
    int d=0;
    int e=0;
    int f=0;

    while (c == 0 || a + b !=0){
        printf("Feed me two numbers please: \n");
        scanf ("%d %d", &a, &b);
        if (c == c + 1){
            printf("Welcome to my world!\n\n");
        }
        if (c = 0){
            d = a + b;
            e = d;
        }
        else if (a + b > d){
            d = a + b;
        }
        else if (a + b < e){
            e = a + b;
        }
        if (a < f){
            f=a;
        }
        c = c + 1;
    }

    printf("Now hear this:%d %d\n\n", d, e, f);
}
```

Comment: lol yeah, how can c equal both itself and itself plus one? Maybe `if (c > 0) c++;`? Nvm just saw the update.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
if (c = 0)
```

you're *assigning* `0` to `c`, the expression of the assignment returns the **assigned value**, so the expression will be *always* evaluated to false as it's equivalent to `if(0)`, it should be `if(c == 0)`.

Also

```
if (c == c + 1)
```

doesn't make any sense, what exactly do you mean? I think it should be `c > 0`.

In all cases, you should use the debugger, it can save you a lot of time, and will help you to really understand your code.